# Composer install error when run in shell script

Tags: php, shell, laravel, composer-php

I have shell script for that is executed before start of the application. 
This is the shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/composer install
/usr/local/bin/php artisan optimize
/usr/local/bin/php artisan key:generate
```

when i try to execute this script i get this error

```
Running composer as root/super user is highly discouraged as packages, plugins and scripts cannot always be trusted


[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
 " is not defined.
 Did you mean this?
   install
```

The composer executable is installed and works when called from the command line

Answer (score 1):

The trick is putting it like this

```
#!/bin/sh
`/usr/local/bin/composer install`
`/usr/local/bin/php artisan optimize`
`/usr/local/bin/php artisan key:generate`
```